# How do I get audio to play when I hover over an image?

Tags: javascript, html

I'am a complete beginner in coding I was just practicing making a simple prank web page for my nephew (its an inside joke of ours) I know the solution might be easy but I cannot figure it out on account of being a beginner and still learning. I want the audio to play when I hover my mouse on the image and to stop playing when my mouse is out how can I modify my code (given below) to do that?. I tried with the onclick event and it worked. Thank you in advance

```
</head>
<body>
   <script>
       function play(){
           var audio = document. getElementById("audio")
           audio.play();
       }
   </script>
    <img src="moolikeacow.jpg" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="rickroll.mp3"></audio>
</body>
```

Comment: so mouseenter and mouseleave?

Comment: yes that but I cannot figure out how to play the audio using mouseenter and mouseleave. or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code a bit. First of all moving the script element to the end of the document to make sure that all elements are loaded before referring to them. Second I made event listeners for both click, mouseover and mouseout events. I also added a function for stopping the audio.

```html
<body>
  <img id="img" src="moolikeacow.jpg" />
  <audio id="audio" src="rickroll.mp3"></audio>
  <script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    
    function play() {
      audio.play();
    }
    
    function stop() {
      audio.pause();
    }
    
    img.addEventListener('click', play);
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', play);
    img.addEventListener('mouseout', stop);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked!

Answer (score 1):

The First Problem why it doesn't work is that you wrote javaScript top of the html elements as a result javaScript can't grab those elements because those elements are created after javaScript.

Second Problem is You Added The Click event to image so only if you click it will start the audio, not on hover. You should add the `mouseover` event listener instead of `click` to make that work.

I just wrote a script that works well as you are looking for and with good comments so you can use or learn how it's working
https://gist.github.com/mmestiyak/93b4ee8952337f7847e3aab4f6521174
You Used Inline Event in Image But There is much more things to do with addEventListener method that comes in every element you grab in javaScript.
You can give a look  at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to know more about addEventListener

Here you can see the live version: **https://h7qym.csb.app/**
hover on the image and just wait for some seconds to see the magic

> If Any other things to know please let me know, i enjoy help you

Comment: WHY is the solution on another site? The code should be here, not on github

Comment: @epascarello i'm extremely sorry, i'm new here contributing, i just changed that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$('a').hover(function(){
    PlaySound('mySound');// calling playsound function
},function(){
    StopSound('mySound');// calling stopsound function
});
```

and change your `anchor tag` like,

```html
<a href="#">Hover Over Me To Play</a>
```

Comment: The assumption here is that OP know jquery. Top make this example understandable you need to write the functions as well as referring to jquery.

Comment: Why would one need to change it to a link???